# Routing doesn't work when I use canActivate in Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, nativescript, canactivate

I have a project in Nativescript. My problem in my project is in CanActivate. My canActivate don't navigate in another page when use AuthGuard.

I have this routing.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'fp', component: FirstPageComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'outsidelogin',
    component: outsideloginComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginFirstComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: outsideloginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthResetGuard],
    children: [
       { path: 'resetPasswordRequest/:id', component: ResetPassIdComponent }
    ]
  },

    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/fp', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

in AuthResetGuard.ts I have this code:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let productId = route.params.id;
    if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/test/resetPasswordRequest/' + productId]);
    console.log('/test/resetPasswordRequest/' + productId)
    return true;

}
```

In this ResetPassIdComponent .ts I have

```
  ngOnInit(): any {
    let myid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id")
    this.id = myid;
  }
```

ERROR: When I click in http://xxxxxx.com/v1/resetPasswordRequest/11111, My application don't open , only show splash_screen and in console show all of time only

```
JS: /test/resetPasswordRequest/11111
JS: /test/resetPasswordRequest/11111
JS: /test/resetPasswordRequest/11111
JS: /test/resetPasswordRequest/11111
JS: /test/resetPasswordRequest/11111
```

Any idea please, how to solution my problem ?

Comment: You navigate To the url that launches AuthResetGuard which controls the url  test/reset... and calls the same url recursively.

Comment: Can you write some code please?

Comment: What happens if you remove `this.router.navigate(['/test/resetPasswordRequest/' + productId]);` from `AuthResetGuard`? That is redundant i guess.

Comment: If I remove `this.router.navigate(['/test/resetPasswordRequest/' + productId]);` from AuthResetGuard don't navigate in this ResetPassIdComponent  component

Comment: what happen when you manually hit /test/resetPasswordRequest/11111?does it navigate?